# Standard Deviation Using For Loop Isn't Wroking

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to create a program that prompts the user for grades between 0-100. When they input -1, that means they are done entering grades. I need to put the count, average, and standard deviation, but for some reason the output for standard deviation is really off. For example, when I input 50 twice, my standard deviation is 494.97.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grade {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a grade between 0-100?");
  int grade = scanner.nextInt();
  int[] grades = new int[100];
  double sum = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (grade != -1) {
   grades[i] = grade;
   i++;
   sum += grade;
   System.out.println("Enter a grade between 0 100?");
   grade = scanner.nextInt();
  }

  double sumOfDifference = 0;
  double average = sum / i;

  for (int k = 0; k < grades.length; k++) {
   double difference = (grades[k] - average) * (grades[k] - average);
   sumOfDifference += difference;
  }

  double s = Math.sqrt(sumOfDifference / (i - 1));
  System.out.printf("Count: %4d\n", i);
  System.out.printf("Average: %.2f\n", average);
  System.out.printf("Standard Deviation: %.2f\n", s);
 }
}
```

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < grades.length; k++)` should be  `for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have

```
for (int k = 0; k < grades.length; k++) {
   double difference = (grades[k] - average) * (grades[k] - average);
   sumOfDifference += difference;
  }
```

Note that this goes through all of the elements of grades, including the elements that are not yet initialized. This can be fixed by only going through the first i elements, the ones the user inputted.

```
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
   double difference = (grades[k] - average) * (grades[k] - average);
   sumOfDifference += difference;
  }
```